# Add a default value in a given list at positions where elements of a large list are not in a smaller list

Tags: python, list

I have :

- A large list of string
- A smaller list of string, all values being in the large
- A list of values, with the same size as the smaller list

Let's take these lists, meeting the above criteria :

```
Large_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
Short_list = ['b','c','f']
List_values = [2,4,3]
```

I would like to add 0 in List_values where an element of Short_list is not in Large_list.

Expected result :

```
[0,2,4,0,0,3]
```

How please could I do ?

Comment: It looks like you got this from a job test. Ask your doubt do not ask for someone to write code for you.

Comment: It is not from a job test and I don't see why that question shouldn't have a place on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
In [810]: for c,i in enumerate(Large_list): 
     ...:     if i not in Short_list: 
     ...:         List_values.insert(c,0) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [811]: List_values                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[811]: [0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 3]
```